# × Error: Aplicación (...): No se devolvió nada de render. Por lo general, esto significa que falta una declaración de devolución. O

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

No sé qué me falta porque render no me quiere renderizar nada; me gustaría que me dijeran si saben cual es el error para poder corregirlo

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: Este es el componente App]

```
import Header from "./Components/static/Header"
import "./style/style.scss"
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch, 
    Route
} from "react-router-dom"
import Inicio from "./Components/pages/Inicio"
const App = () => {
    <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/Inicio">
                <Inicio />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

No retornas nada en la función App, para que en los componente funcionales de React se renderize las funciones deben de tener un return, en tu caso App no retorna nada de ahí el error.

```
const App = () => {
    <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/Inicio">
                <Inicio />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
}
```

En una arrow function con {} es como si fuera una función normal, debes de llamar a return, en cambio si usas () directamente se considera que lo siguiente es el return así que las dos opcion válidas serían:

```
const App = () => {
   return (
    <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/Inicio">
                <Inicio />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/Inicio">
                <Inicio />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
)
```